# C++: Why does this logical expression evaluate to false?

Tags: c++, boolean, boolean-expression

```
int a = 10, b = 12, c = 8

!((a < 5) || (c < (a + b)))
```

I just tried it in a compiler and it was false.

Comment: Break it down step by step and tell us what you think each step should result in.

Comment: Wooops! I got confused by parenthesis. Nevermind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner expression:

```
(a < 5) || (c < (a + b))
```

evaluates `a < 5` as `false` (since `a` is `10`) and `c < (a + b)` as `true` (since `8` is less than `10+12`). Performing a Boolean "or" operation on `false` and `true` gives you `true`.

And, given that the next thing you do to that value is the `!` (inversion), that `true` turns into a `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
c < (a + b) == 8 < (10 + 12) == 8 < 22 == true
a < 5 == 10 < 5 == false
(a < 5) || (c < (a + b)) == false || true == true
!((a < 5) || (c < (a + b))) == !(true) == false
```